# How to add a small image icon in front of an article title in joomla?

Tags: image, joomla, addition, title

I am creating some articles in Joomla website and make them scroll in the home page. I need to add a "new" image icon for newly added articles in the scrolling of articles. I don't have an option in the scrolling module to add it.

Can any one suggest me a joomla module for article title scrolling (vertical direction).

OR

How to add a small image icon in front of an article title.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could probably override the layout for the module, and add a class to the title if it is new. Like:

- Copy the file modules/[mod_yourscrollingmodule]/tmpl/default.php to templates/[yourtemplate]/[mod_yourscrollingmodule]/default.php
- modify the code in default.php to add a class to the title tag if article is newer than some kriteria
- Modify the stylesheet for the template to show an icon if this class is set

If you provide some more info from your module it would be easier to guide you